# Push an array in firebase in child position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array from a table i extracted which im trying to push in a parent from an object as an child. I understand firebase isnt really made for arrays so how do i best around is? This is waht I have;

```
const exerciseName = document.getElementById("exercise-search");
const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML;

var HoeveelheidArr=[];
var Gewicht=[];

function getData(){
    $('#resultTable .HoeveelheidField > input ').each(function() {
        HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#resultTable .GewichtField > input').each(function() {
        Gewicht.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(HoeveelheidArr);
    console.log(Gewicht);
}
```

Here is the part im stuck, its teh part which im attempting to send the array to the DB and put in under the "setAm" object :

```
function writeData(){
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
        nameExercise: exerciseName.value,
        setAm: setAmount,
    });
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise/setAm")({
        HoeveelheidArr,
        Gewicht,
    });
}
```

How can I best go around this? I keep getting the error

> TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref(...) is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in that last statement, as you're missing a `set` call:

```
firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
    nameExercise: exerciseName.value,
    setAm: setAmount,
});
firebase.database().ref("Exercise/setAm").set({ // this line changed
    HoeveelheidArr,
    Gewicht,
});
```

---

The result of these two statements can also be achieved with a single call to `set`:

```
firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
    nameExercise: exerciseName.value,
    setAm: {
      HoeveelheidArr,
      Gewicht,
    }
});
```

---

If you want to create a list of child nodes under `Exercise` [sic], you can use Firebase's `push()` method for that.

```
firebase.database().ref("Exercise/setAm").push({
    HoeveelheidArr,
    Gewicht,
});
firebase.database().ref("Exercise/setAm").push({
    HoeveelheidArr,
    Gewicht,
});
```

This creates two child nodes under `setAm`, each with a unique key.

For more on `push()` vs using an array, see the blog post [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).